# How to fill The form in a popup

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'am trying to automate http://rose.99ats.com/careers.aspx

After clicking on "signup", I couldn't find the element Popup. I used `getWindowHandle()`, also used `driver.swithchto()`, but getting error. I can't find element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's in a new `iframe`, you need to use [`driver.switchTo().frame()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10887059/1177636) is a detailed answer on using `switchTo()`, in which you can't use name/id in your case, index should generally be avoided, so you may try locate the iframe element by css selector or xpath first, then switch to this `WebElement`.

```java
WebElement popup = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[src^='CareerSignUp.aspx']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(popup);
// or by index: driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```