# Selenium does not find element via xpath using Chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Chromedriver to try and find the following element:

```
<td class="section-menuoption"
  onmouseover="this.className='section-menuoption-hilite';"
  onmouseout="this.className='section-menuoption';" align="left"
  onclick="self.jssDetails.location='products.php?xUser=kery&amp;xRand=123';">
  Scheduled Changes
</td>
```

When using the SeleniumIDE in Firefox I can use this selector without issue:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Scheduled Changes')]
```

However, when I attempt to use this selector with the Chromedriver I get a "no such element" error (running via maven).  My Chromedriver code looks likes this:

```
WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Scheduled Changes')]"));
System.out.print(box.getText());
box.click();
```

I've tried different quoting strategies, different xpaths (that also resolve correctly in the SeleniumIDE), but with no success.  The only thing I can think of now is changing my XPath implementation, but I'm not even sure that's possible with Chromedriver.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure it it not in any kind of frames. Otherwise you need switch into the frame first, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-java-using-webdriver).

Then try use css selector instead of XPath. For example (you may need try different variations):

```
WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[onclick*=\"self.jssDetails.location='products.php?xUser=kery&amp;xRand=123';\"]"));
```

Also, you might want to post every XPaths you have tried, to help us analyse.