# Find elements inside forms and iframe using Java and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, iframe, selenium

I'm trying to access elements that are present under `<form> <iFrame> <form> elements </form> </iFrame> </form>`.

Could you help me on accessing these *'elements'*, which I'm working with Selenium Webdriver and JAVA?

**Issue Encountered:** Able to reach the destination page (where the above elements are present), but those elements are not recognized with my code.

**Overview of XML structure:**

```
<body>
    <form action="https://abcd/efgh/" name="outerForm" method="post" target="iFrameTitle">
        <iframe width="700" height="600" src="" title="Frame for Java Test" name="iFrameTitle" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0">
            <form id="innerFormID" name="innerForm" action="/xxx/xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <fieldset id="ncDetailsInner">
                    <div id="element1">
                        <label for="label1">
                        <abbr title="Required field">*</abbr></label>
                        <input name="label2" type="text" maxlength="30" id="cardHolder" value="" >
                    </div>

                    <div id="element2">
                        <label for="label3">Label3 <abbr title="Required field">*</abbr></label>
                        <div id="element3">
                            <label for="label4">Label4<abbr title="Required field">*</abbr></label>
                            <input id="label5" name="labelname5" type="text" maxlength="19" value="">
                        </div>

                        <div id="element4">
                            <label for="label6">Label6</label>
                            <input id="label7" name="labelname7" type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" class="text disabled" disabled="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form> 

        </iframe>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Code Extract:**

```
WebDriverWait wait_iframe = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20000);

wait_iframe.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.id("element2"))));

calling_function(sh1.getCell(col + 10, row).getContents(), 
                sh1.getCell(col + 11, row).getContents(),
                sh1.getCell(col + 12, row).getContents(), 
                sh1.getCell(col + 14, row).getContents());                      

public static void called_funciton(String string1, String string2,
        String string3, String string4) {
        driver.findElement(By.name("Element1 Name")).sendKeys(string1);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Element2 ID")).sendKeys(string2);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Element3 ID")).sendKeys(string3);
        driver.findElement(By.id("Element4 ID")).sendKeys(string4);
        driver.findElement(By.name("submitButton")).click();
    }
```

Do let me know if require any further details!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch between frames in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Before you try searching for the elements within the iframe you will have to switch Selenium focus to the iframe.

Try this before searching for the elements within the iframe:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("iFrameTitle")));
```

Comment: As suggested, added below...but I am stuck with same issue yet



`public static void called_funciton(String string1, String string2, String string3, String string4) {  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("iFrameTitle")));
  
  driver.findElement(By.name("Element1 Name")).sendKeys(string1);
  driver.findElement(By.id("Element2 ID")).sendKeys(string2);
  driver.findElement(By.id("Element3 ID")).sendKeys(string3);
  driver.findElement(By.id("Element4 ID")).sendKeys(string4);
  driver.findElement(By.name("submitButton")).click();
 }`

Comment: Try putting the new switchTo line as the very first line in the code block.  I.e. before `WebDriverWait wait_iframe` before you do anything else.

Comment: Thank you, this time I am able to move a step further, however stuck with an exception:



`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at roll_forward_test.account_creation.thistle_home(xyz_creation.java:680)
 at roll_forward_test.account_creation.main(xyz_creation.java:463)`



the line **(xyz_creation.java:680)** refers to `driver.findElement(By.name("Element1 Name")).sendKeys(string1);` on the called function


and 



the line **(xyz_creation.java:463)** refers to the calling function.

`calling_function(S1, S2, S3, S4);`

please advice!

Comment: If your original question about accessing elements in iframes has been answered, then please mark this answer as accepted and we can look at the subsequent issues.

Comment: I spent hours trying to find a solution, you put me on the right path. Thank you!

Comment: Here is the official web site of Selenium for [Working with IFrames and frames](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/) using examples in multiple languages!

Answer (score 69):

When using an iframe, you will first have to switch to the iframe, before selecting the elements of that iframe

You can do it using:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));
//do your stuff
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

In case if your frameId is dynamic, and you only have one iframe, you can use something like:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
```

Comment: +1 for the `switchTo().defaultContent()` i'm guessing that's how you unselect the frame after your work is done.

Answer (score 4):

On *Selenium >= 3.41 (C#)* the rigth syntax is:

```
webDriver = webDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("icontent")));
```

Comment: this is a **Java** question!

Answer (score 1):

By using https://github.com/nick318/FindElementInFrames
You can find webElement across all frames:

```
SearchByFramesFactory searchFactory = new SearchByFramesFactory(driver);
SearchByFrames searchInFrame = searchFactory.search(() -> driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")));
Optional<WebElement> elem = searchInFrame.getElem();
```

Answer (score 1):

For python users:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[6]/div[2]/div/iframe"))
```

And also switch back:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: This may work when using python,  but since OP asked expressly about Java it is not really an answer to their question...