# Selenium WebDriver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*")) can not find element, C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am looking for element with ID "lastdays_day" as:

```
var elements = WebDriver.FindElements(By.Id("lastdays_day"));
```

but elements.Count is 0.

Even:

```
WebDriver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("*"))
```

can not list this element

I have tried Thread.Sleep(5000) after page load but doesn't work. 
I have tried

```
Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent
```

or

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0)
```

but doesn't work.

Any ideas?

[image: structure of the page]

Comment: You have to find the iFrame first. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247490/find-elements-inside-forms-and-iframe-using-java-and-selenium-webdriver

Comment: i am trying it but i have difficulty locate correct frame. It seems Selenium doesn't see even the frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent;` is to switch *out* of the frame.

`Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);` won't work either since indexes in the html starts from 1.

`Driver.SwitchTo()` can receives ID/name as parameter, so the switch command should look like

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ombframe"); // switch to first frame
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("MainFrame"); // switch to second frame
```

As a side note, the ID of the element is `lastdays_days` with 's', not `lastdays_day`. It will also return only one element as ID is unique, so you can use `WebDriver.FindElement`

```
IWebElement element = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("lastdays_days"));
```

Comment: When i use 
    Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("MainFrame");

i end up with: An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchFrameException' 

Additional information: No frame element found with name or id MainFrame

Comment: @mojmir.novak Try to switch to the parent frame first `Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ombframe");`, and then to the frame with the element.

Comment: finally, it works :-) 
Please, it is there any way how to determine list of frames in page / or as children in parent frames?

Comment: @mojmir.novak You can see it in the html tree by the alignment. For example, frames `AppletFrame` and `MainFrame` are siblings, and children of the element above them with `<frameset>` tag.

Comment: what i mean is if is here any function in Selenium what can give me a list of frames in runtime to I can search the element recursively in whole page. There are times i don't know the page structure or i don't want to care about frames.

Comment: @mojmir.novak No, there isn't. You have to tell the webdriver how to find the elements so it can interact with them, so it has to be done manually before running the code.

Comment: @Guy, SwitchTo().Frame is 0 based and not 1 based when an index is used as argument.