# Not able to locate the input text element tried id,class,name,xpath in Selenium 2.47

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am new to `Selenium WebDriver`. I am stuck in locating one element for the following input text.

`HTML` code is

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1" size="30" name="flights_search[from_location_name]" id="flights_search_from_location_name" class="flight-from ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
<input id="flights_search_from_location" class="wego-from-code" type="hidden" name="flights_search[from_location]" value="">
```

Code I tried :

- By ID

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.id("flights_search_from_location_name")).clear();
  ```
- By xpath

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form/fieldset/span[2]/input[1]")).clear();
  ```

I have tried with `id`, `name`, `classname` and `xpath`, but it is not able to locate this element.

Comment: Show locators that failed to find target element. Also share exception log if you got any

Comment: <input type="text" tabindex="1" size="30" name="flights_search[from_location_name]" id="flights_search_from_location_name" class="flight-from ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
<input id="flights_search_from_location" class="wego-from-code" type="hidden" name="flights_search[from_location]" value="">

Comment: Which code you used when trying to locate this element? Please show it.

Comment: The locators i tried are id, name and xpath.

Comment: Xpath driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form/fieldset/span[2]/input[1]")).clear();

Comment: i tried with id also driver.findElement(By.id("flights_search_from_location_name")).clear();

Comment: And which exception are you getting in this last case (using id) ?

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

Comment: Ok, follow @Andersson instructions in his answer, it could be timing issue or iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wait until required `input` field appears in `DOM`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("flights_search_from_location_name"))).clear();
```

If element still couldn't be located, check whether `input` field located inside an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_iframe.asp). If so, you need [to switch to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247490/find-elements-inside-forms-and-iframe-using-java-and-selenium-webdriver/24247565#24247565) `iframe` to be able to handle elements inside it

Comment: I tried by adding wait to input field below exception coming "org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.id: flights_search_from_location_name" and also this element is not located inside iframe

Comment: Can you share page `URL` or it's confidential?

Comment: I am trying to Automate Booking Flight page in this demo Website. http://phptravels.net/flightsw and in this 'from location" input field

Comment: Yes, `input` located inside an `iframe`. Try to switch to it with `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));`

Comment: @PriyaVerma Try to increase the time from 10 to 20 and also make sure that the element is available. For that you can inspect the element in the browser and check for the id.

Comment: Oh Thanks @Andersson. I didn't notice the ifame. Thanks for your help

Comment: @PriyaVerma, Welcome. Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it solved your problem. Thanks