# how to click on button which is present in a frame using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
[image][1]
```

The button present in the frame, i have written code for switch the frame and click on the facebook button but the click operation is not performed, give s my html code please help me out

Html frame

```
<document>
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body id="social_login" class="plugin">
<!--[if IE]><div id="ie"><![endif]-->
<div id="social_login_frame" class="frame">
<div id="content">
<div id="providers" class="providers providers_unpaginated">
<div id="providers_group_1" class="providers_group">
<div class="providers_block" role="application">
<div class="providers_row">
<div id="provider_facebook" class="provider">
<a id="button_facebook" class="button" href="#" rel="nofollow" title="Login with Facebook" role="button" aria-label="Login with Facebook" aria-haspopup="true">
<div id="name_facebook" class="name">Facebook</div>
</div>
<div id="provider_google" class="provider">
<div id="provider_linkedin" class="provider">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXMDe.png
```

Webdriver code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='contentagent']/div[2]/‌​ul/li[2]/a")).click(‌​); 
Thread.sleep(1000); 
driver.switchTo().frame(0); 
Thread.sleep(500); 
driver.findElement(By.id("button_facebook")).click();
```

Comment: here is my code                                                            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='contentagent']/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  driver.switchTo().frame(0);
  Thread.sleep(500);
  driver.findElement(By.id("button_facebook")).click();

Comment: Can you provide some more information as below: 1. Provide the code you tried out for switching to the frame. 2. Provide more HTML DOM. 3. Share the screenshot .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find elements inside forms and iframe using Java and Selenium WebDriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247490/find-elements-inside-forms-and-iframe-using-java-and-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: <document>
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body id="social_login" class="plugin">
<!--[if IE]><div id="ie"><![endif]-->
<div id="social_login_frame" class="frame">
<div id="content">
<div id="providers" class="providers providers_unpaginated">
<div id="providers_group_1" class="providers_group">
<div class="providers_block" role="application">
<div class="providers_row">
<div id="provider_facebook" class="provider">

Comment: <a id="button_facebook" class="button" href="#" rel="nofollow" title="Login with Facebook" role="button" aria-label="Login with Facebook" aria-haspopup="true">
<div id="name_facebook" class="name">Facebook</div>
</div>
<div id="provider_google" class="provider">
<div id="provider_linkedin" class="provider">
</div>

Comment: @VenkataSrinuvasareddy can you please update your question putting all these info for better readability & understanding?

Comment: @Dev did u see my image?

Comment: @VenkataSrinuvasareddy Thanks, saw the image. Can you please copy the HTML DOM in the Question area for better readability & understanding? Additionally put the code which you have tried in the Question area as well. Thanks

Comment: @Dev i have updated html code with DOM, and i want to click on any one of these buttons like Facebook, Google or Linkedin which you can see in the image

Comment: @VenkataSrinuvasareddy can you share the URL you are trying to automate or it is confidential?

Comment: By the time I get back to you with a working code of similar situation try out the thread provided by @Andersson in the third dialog.

Comment: @Dev can u plz send me the code

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Get the parent window handle.
2. Click on the Link.
3. Get all the Window Handles.(To confirm its a frame/iframe)
4. Switch to your frame.
5. Click on the element.
6. Go back to parent window.

Your probable code may look like:

```
/First Get parent window,means current window handle
    String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("Parent Window Title "+driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='contentagent']/div[2]/‌​ul/li[2]/a")).click();
    //Frame Handling begins here
    //Get All Tabs or Window handles and iterate using for each loop
    for(String handle:driver.getWindowHandles()) 
    {
        System.out.println(handle);
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
     }

    //switch to frame using frame name
    driver.switchTo().frame("your_frame_name"); // replace by your frame name
    String childtFrame = driver.getWindowHandle();
    System.out.println("Child Frame Title "+driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.id("button_facebook")).click();
    //Go back to Parent window
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: i used above code, my test is passed but did not perform click operation on the facebook button

Comment: given frame as driver.switchTo().frame(0);

Comment: @VenkataSrinuvasareddy instead of "0" provide the "actual_frame_name". To get the frame name, when the frame opens inspect the frame in the body section. You will find the frame name.

Comment: did not perform click operation after pass the frame name also      very difficulty

Comment: I have modified the code, paste me the output here.

Comment: see the output    Parent Window Title Estimated Home Value for 658 Davis Ln, Wayne, PA 19087 | FB Test Brokerage
{ae60f4f9-53a8-44d1-867f-c2e1ef0ccd05}
Child Frame Title Estimated Home Value for 658 Davis Ln, Wayne, PA 19087 | FB Test Brokerage

Comment: please view above output