# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I am trying to automate a travel application. I logged in with user name and  I tried to click book travel. But is showing the below error while I was trying to click travel.

> FAILED: BookTravel org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable
>   to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='ctl00_mnuTraveln0']/table/tbody/tr/td/a"}

screen shot

[image]

Comment: in which language you code ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Have you tried `By.linkText("Book Travel")` or some variation? What else have you tried? Update your question with what you've tried and what the results were.

Comment: I have tried with link text , but not working.  I tried with xpath, href, linktext.. I think i need to handle this with frames. I am not sure how to search for the frame id or how to handle frames.. The output is i am getting " No such element exception". This could be handle by frames.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know C#,
this code might help you,

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("*//a[text()='Book Travel']"));
```

in java,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("*//a[text()='Book Travel']"));
```

check this might helpful,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("*//a[@href='TravelRequest.aspx?PID=1']"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("*//a[contains(@class,'MenuItemStyle')]"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("*//a[contains(@href,'TravelRequest')]"));
```

above will not work if there is frames so,
you have to calculate frames,
how many frames are there is shown using,

```
int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
driver.switchTo().frame(size);
```

also using webelement we can switch too,

```
driver.switchTo().frame(WebElement);
```

switch between parent or default frames,

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Code is based on Java language.. Not working, i have tried your method @ashish. Same error coming. Thanks!

Comment: can you paste html sample ?

Comment: @Infern0  <a class="ctl00_mnuTravel_1 MenuItemStyle ctl00_mnuTravel_3" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;" href="TravelRequest.aspx?PID=1">Book Travel</a>

Comment: Same error is coming ... Is it possible with href in selenium. If so, please suggest me

Comment: if you manually apply the xpath of @Ashish, you will see that is working and highlight the element. HTML sample of the html not the element will help, because it can be in iframe.

Comment: @Infern0 ashish xpath is ok. But it is not working. I think , it is in frames.. Can you please suggest me to done this with frame code

Comment: @Ashish Kamble. Thanks for the code. Unfortunately it is not working. Can u help if a code to handle frame

Comment: You may need to inspect for the frame title or id or name.  simply meaning is there is tag with the name <iframe> Simple,  
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("iFrameTitle")));

Comment: ok before going to find element you have to switch to specif frame first By using frame name or id ok 
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("Book")));
This switches to Book Frame then call FindElement() will surely help you Look this 
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247490/find-elements-inside-forms-and-iframe-using-java-and-selenium-webdriver>

Comment: Where to get this frame Id? Frame Id is same  Id to all modules, ? I am seeing this class name as same  in all the modules-- "ctl00_mnuTravel_1 MenuItemStyle ctl00_mnuTravel_3". shall i take this as frame Id,,,

Comment: I found something, called frame, but not in my exact module, some where in the bottom.... <iframe src="../flipkart_usermanual/Help.html" style="background-color: White;" height="500" width="800">
                                    </iframe>   . Is this the frame name?