# Selenium displays NoSuchElementException despite the element being there

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

So I made a short bit of selenium code, it isn't letting me select elements though! I do not understand. I try copy and pasting examples and none work because of this.

It says: `NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element #login\-input`

Here is my java code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
driver.get( "https://www.ticketmaster.com/review" );
WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement( By.id( "login-input" ) );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find elements inside forms and iframe using Java and Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247490/find-elements-inside-forms-and-iframe-using-java-and-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 1):

Your login form is inside the `iframe`. Switch your driver first, try the bellow code :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
driver.get( "https://www.ticketmaster.com/review" );

driver.switchTo().frame("loginFrame");
WebElement inputElement = driver.findElement( By.id( "login-input" ) );
inputElement.sendKeys("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

The *username* and *password* fields are within an `iframe`, so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get( "https://www.ticketmaster.com/review" );
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe#loginFrame")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("label[for='login-input']"))).sendKeys("FX_NINJA");
  ```