# Why no elements can be tergeted on this website?

Tags: java, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium to type in data in inputboxes. But I cant get any element (NoSuchElementException). Problem is only with this [site](https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/web/wyszukiwarka-krs/strona-glowna).

I tried searching by name/id but it failed.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();        
driver.get("https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/web/wyszukiwarka-krs/strona-glowna");
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
System.out.println("Successfully opened the website");
WebElement wb = driver.findElement(By.id("rejestrPrzedsiebiorcy"));
```

My goal (for now) is just to get this element :P.

Comment: _...cant get any element..._ which element are you trying to access?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find elements inside forms and iframe using Java and Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247490/find-elements-inside-forms-and-iframe-using-java-and-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the form is included in the source via `<iframe>` element. You can see that it has attribute `src="https://ekrs.ms.gov.pl/krsrdf/krs/wyszukiwaniepodmiotu?"`. If you go to that link, you will see standalone form. The question is - how to access an included source? It's quite simple ;)

1. Find the `<iframe>` element:

   `WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='portlet-body']/div/iframe"))`
2. Switch to that frame:

   `driver.switchTo().frame(frame)`

And that's it! Now you are in the `<iframe>` element context, and you can search inside it. so this will work now:

```
WebElement wb = driver.findElement(By.id("rejestrPrzedsiebiorcy"));
```

To switch back (get out of the frame context) you just have to call:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Note that this site has dynamically generated ids to prevent automation, and uses CaptchaV3 (you can see I used xpath expression to find the iframe). Selenium is easily detectable if you are not careful.

Comment: It worked. Thx dude :D.

Just one more thing. When i press SearchButton ("Szukaj") it pops up a window "please enter proper code". Do You know what might be the cause?

Comment: @KonstantyMaciejLachowicz You probably need to fill `Numer KRS:` input or something else. I don't know the internal logic.EDIT tested, not working.

Comment: I think ReCaptcha blocks selenium actions. For example, if you use `element.click()`, selenium "teleports" cursor to that element. It's detected, and the site blocks you from using it. Take a look at [org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html). You need to "slow down selenium". But that's all just a guess. And it might be impossible or really hard.

Comment: Nevermind, ReCaptcha just detects if you are using WebDriver, so there is no salvation.

Comment: TO ANYONE INTERESTED: I dodged ReCaptcha by clearing cache and cookies before clicking "search" button.

Comment: @KonstantyMaciejLachowicz I checked the cookies, and it's enough to delete one: `driver.manage().deleteCookieNamed("BIGipServerPOOL_S24_KRS_PCL")`. No need to remove all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Carefully observe the HTML code after inspecting required element. If you element is inside `<iframe>` then you need to switch on to frame first and then find that element.

below is the way to switch to frame:

`driver.switchTo().frame()` method takes one of the three possible arguments:

**A number.**

Select a frame by its (zero-based) index. That is, if a page has three frames, the first frame would be at index 0, the second at index 1 and the third at index 2. Once the frame has been selected, all subsequent calls on the WebDriver interface are made to that frame.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0)
```

**A name or ID.**

Select a frame by its name or ID. Frames located by matching name attributes are always given precedence over those matched by ID.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("name here");
```

**A previously found WebElement.**

Select a frame using its previously located WebElement.

```
    WebElement iframeElement = driver.findElement(By.id("IF1"));

    //now use the switch command
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframeElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `driver.findElement(By.id("form-main"));` first, then `driver.findElement(By.id("rejestrPrzedsiebiorcy"));` again.