# How to Write a cssSelector for the complex jQuery selector below

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have below jQuery selector. I check it with data from the browser developer console.

```
jQuery("iframe#msg_body").contents().find("html body div span").text()
```

And I need to use this for cssSelector in selenium.
for example as below format

```
By expectedOutput  = By.cssSelector(The_expression_I_need);
```

Can any one tell me how to do that ?

Comment: Are you sure your question is somehow related to `java`?

Comment: yes lealceldeiro

Comment: Yes correct. issue is I cannot use it exactly as below
jQuery("iframe#msg_body").contents().find("html body div span").text()

Comment: You cannot do this via a CSS selector, as CSS does not cross frames. However it appears that Selenium does have alternative methods, such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247490/find-elements-inside-forms-and-iframe-using-java-and-selenium-webdriver

Comment: For first you need to move WebDriver to iframe: `driver.switchTo().frame("msg_body");` and after use WebDriver to find element and get the text: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html/body/div/span")).getText();`

Comment: @KunLun That is not a CSS selector. That is an XPath.

Comment: @JeffC Ye, my bad. It should be `driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div/span")).getText();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rory McCrossan mentioned, You can't just access the element using CSS selector since it is inside an iframe.

You have to switch to the iframe and search for the element.

```java
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("msg_body"));
By expectedOutput = By.cssSelector("html body div span");
```

Then you can get the element using the locator.

The locator will return all the span tag inside a div tag inside the body tag. So I'm guessing it will most probably get more than one element.