# selectFrame is failing in Dojo pages when using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select a frame in a dojo page with the selenium method shown below is failing

```
driver.switchTo().frame(target);
```

I have passed title attribute as my target value.
For the target i do not have id or name attributes, how could i pass the target value for the below element.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" title="Universal Line Template Configuration" style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="/ucmadmin/ccmadmin-latest?name=universalLineTemplate&key=a91ffd45-a34f-bc90-c159-1bef9e7c9921&permission=3">
```

When i check by clicking a button in a dojo page, the selenium IDE is showing two operations for a single click, as shown below

```
click     id=g_btnExpandAll_label
click     name=g_btnExpandAll
```

Is anything to be done apart from the line `driver.switchTo().frame(target);`?

Comment: Just locate the `<iframe>` using xpath or css instead of using an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to locate the frame first. For example, by xpath relying on the `title` tag:

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//iframe[@title="Universal Line Template Configuration"]'));
```

The use it as a target:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

See also:

- [How to switch between frames in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)