# ChromeDriver is not switching frames properly

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem to switch properly to frame.

The project is maven project with this `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>betlista</groupId>
    <artifactId>bugs.chromedriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My testing class is:

```
package bugs.chromedriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:/betlista/progs/chromedriver_2.13_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/frames/chrome_test.html");
        driver.switchTo().frame(0); // outer
        try {
            driver.switchTo().frame(1); // menu - ERROR
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

page I used for testing is

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chome frames test</title>
    </head>

    <frameset rows="100%, *">
        <frame src="./outer.html">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

outer frame:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chome frames test - outer</title>
    </head>

    <frameset rows="55, *">
        <frame src="top.html">
        <frameset cols="190,*">
            <frame src="menu.html" name="menu">
            <frame src="content.html"name="content">
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

top frame:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chome frames test - top frame</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        top
    </body>
</html>
```

menu frame:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chome frames test - menu frame</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>menu</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

content frame:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chome frames test - content frame</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        content
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the code exception occurs:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.13.307647 (5a7d0541ebc58e69994a6fb2ed930f45261f3c29) on port 25190
Only local connections are allowed.
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: no such frame
  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.95)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.13.307647 (5a7d0541ebc58e69994a6fb2ed930f45261f3c29),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 20 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a6c4449dc285928ba024779344f5423c58', time: '2014-03-27 11:29:39'
System info: host: 'CZCHOWN5019295', ip: '2.252.210.20', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Session ID: b30602d7260eefcf7e7c30b348271eb0
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\msuska\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir29108_23597}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=39.0.2171.95, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:857)
    at bugs.chromedriver.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

phantomjsdriver is using [selenium chrome driver](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver) in version 2.41.0 so I tried also to upgrade to last version 2.44.0, one have to solve few problems:

When dependency is added, there is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonElement` so I had to manually add gson dependency - new `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>betlista</groupId>
    <artifactId>bugs.chromedriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.detro</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.44.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

next there is `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions`, Test source needs to be modified slightly:

```
// ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // old
DesiredCapabilities cdc = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cdc);
```

but same error again - `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: no such frame`.

The same works fine, when `ChromeDriver` is replaced with `PhantomJSDriver`.

There is old [Chrome driver issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=107).

**edit:**
I believe, that this is error - the best understanding I got from [window.frameElement](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_frameElement.asp) description.

It seems to me, like `switchTo` should work like this:

1. at the beginning there is one frame - from JS `window.frames.length` returns 1
2. so I have to "switch" to first frame and `window.frames[0].frames.length` returns 3
3. the second on is menu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch between frames in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding: `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` before switching to a new frame.

Comment: basically this is "ignore the first switch" solution

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0); // outer
...
driver.switchTo().frame(1); // menu - ERROR
```

The first `switchTo()` will switch to your frame, **not** the outer frame as your comment *incorrectly* points out. The second `switchTo()` will fail, since there is no frame that is contained in there.

The solution is to drop the first `switchTo()`, since even your intent would effectively do nothing, and make the **second** `driver.switchTo().frame(0); // menu`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, there is a problem with index based navigation only.

Trying to achieve the same by tag names works as expected (in both 2.41.0 and 2.44.0 dependency versions)

```
    List<WebElement> frames = driver.findElementsByTagName("frame");
    driver.switchTo().frame(frames.get(0));
    List<WebElement> frames2 = driver.findElementsByTagName("frame");
    driver.switchTo().frame(frames2.get(1));
```