# Selenium/python - locating an element with the same ID

Tags: python, selenium, element

Ok, I have an iframe with 3 tabs. On each of these tabs there is an element with the same ID, class but different value. How am I supposed to locate each of them separately?

Comment: Possibly with xpath or css. Provide the `html` of all three if possible

Comment: It is worth considering: same `id` on one page, is generally considered a bug.

Comment: You should consider change the HTML to avoid duplication of ids according to the HTML specification.

Comment: Perhaps this is not his own page.

Comment: I know, I'll suggest this change to the our developer.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you know how to [deal with iframes with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java) and that it isn't a first blocker for you.

Then to answer your question, you can either:

- use an xpath selector:

  - `*[@id="tabid"][1]` will select the first element with the id `tabid`.
  - `*[@id="tabid"][2]` will select the second element with the id `tabid`.
  - etc.
- use a CSS selector:

  - `#tabid:nth-child(1)`
  - `#tabid:nth-child(2)`
  - etc.

Comment: To be more specific Tab1 has a button1 (id=submit, value=xx) Tab 2 has a button2 (id=submit, value=xy),..how do I locate for example: button 2?

Comment: `//*[@id="tabid"][2]/button[@id='submit']` or directly `//*button[@id='submit'][2]`.

Comment: I tried: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*input[@id='submit'][2]").click() but I`m getting syntax error

Comment: Can you try without the `*`?

Comment: You have to [switch to the iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java) first, did you do that? Can you access the iframe content?