# WebDriver - How to locate iframe without id

Tags: selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to switch to an iframe in order to locate an element, but I'm unable to locate the iframe since it has no `id` or `name`

```html
<div id="eyein-modal" style="display: block; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 90000000; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); overflow: auto; opacity: 1;">
<iframe style="display: block; width:90%; height:90%; border: 0px; margin: 2.5% auto; z-index: 90000000; overflow: hidden;" scrolling="no" src="about:blank">
<html>
   <head>
   <body class="">
      <div id="modal">
      <div id="modal-header">
      <div id="header-logo">
      <div id="title-container" class="">
      <a id="view-event" class="button" target="_blank" href="http://www.link.com">view event</a>
      <div id="close-modal" class="close-dark"></div>
```

`close-modal` is the element I need eventually

Comment: You could try to find it by its tag, assuming there is only 1 iframe.

Comment: .. or if you know which one of how many iframes. By the way, do you really have 90 million layers on your page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aside from providing frame name or id, you can switch to the frame [by index](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#frame%28int%29) (zero-based):

> Select a frame by its (zero-based) index. That is, if a page has three
>   frames, the first frame would be at index "0", the second at index "1"
>   and the third at index "2". Once the frame has been selected, all
>   subsequent calls on the WebDriver interface are made to that frame.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);  // assuming this is the first frame on the page
```

Or, you can make a `WebElement` instance by locating the `iframe`, for example, by CSS selector:

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#eyein-modal iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

See also:

- [How to switch between frames in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Comment: You read the OP's mind that he'll will be automating with java only.+1 for that

Comment: I had another iframe I used which had id.
So what I did is "switch to default content: driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
and then I used your solution using CSS selector.
Thanks

Comment: @Madhan yeah, the probability that it was java was quite high because of the OP's previous questions :)

Comment: I was stuck on this for such a long time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone using [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html) in R happens on this little problem, this is what I used:

```
    webElement <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "#dsq-app1")
    remDr$switchToFrame(webElement)
    # note: remDr is the remoteDriver instance that needs to be opened at the beginning
```

or

```
   webElement <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "dsq-app1")
   remDr$switchToFrame(webElement)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem ... using Webdriver with Codeception.  My solution was to run a javascript snippet to give the iframe a name, and then I could switch to it based on name ... details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48123837/1593026

Answer (score 0):

As per the html of the [*iframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) element:

```
<iframe style="display: block; width:90%; height:90%; border: 0px; margin: 2.5% auto; z-index: 90000000; overflow: hidden;" scrolling="no" src="about:blank">
```

It is pretty much evident that the `<iframe>` doesn't have either of the following attributes:

- *id*
- *name*
- *class*
- *title*
- specific value of *src* attribute

In such cases to switch to the desired [*iframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) you can refer to the **preceeding(*sibling*)** [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Java based solutions:

  - Using *xpath* and *`following`*:

    ```
    WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='eyein-modal']//following::iframe[1]"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
    ```
  - Using *xpath* and *`following-sibling`*:

    ```
    WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='eyein-modal']//following-sibling::iframe[1]"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
    ```
  - Using *cssSelector*:

    ```
    WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#eyein-modal +iframe"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
    ```
- Python based solutions:

  - Using *xpath* and *`following`*:

    ```
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='eyein-modal']//following::iframe[1]"))
    ```
  - Using *xpath* and *`following-sibling`*:

    ```
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='eyein-modal']//following-sibling::iframe[1]"))
    ```
  - Using *cssSelector*:

    ```
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#eyein-modal +iframe"))
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472200/7429447)
- [Selenium - How to locate elements on iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51621710/7429447)