# Trying to capture html code within a class with soapui and selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, soapui

I need to capture all the html code within a frame in a webpage, all the data seems to be within a class as follow:

```
<div class="productos-mant">
```

Within this class you can find all the items like

```
<a class="round-item" href="https://www.supermercado.com/my-basket/profile" data-id ...etc</a>
```

Is any method that allow me to catpure to a .txt all the html info from this class in the frame?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for `all the html code within a frame in a webpage`. First, call the `switchTo()` method using frame name or id, e.g.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame_name");
driver.switchTo().frame("frame_id");
```

You can find a detailed discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200). Once you are within the intended frame, you can grab the entire HTML using `getPageSource()`.

```
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Comment: there isn´t a frame name or id, the html data is inside the class, the only way to capture is with copy outerhtml option, is there any method to get it?

Comment: @FC_Javier Yes, there are ways to do that even. Can you please raise a new Question with your new requirement please? We will be happy to help you out.