# Get text found between span - selenium

Tags: java, html, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Inspect element from Google Chrome:

```
<div class="form-style-abc">
   <fieldset>
    <legend><span class="number">*</span>Search Zone</legend>
```

Need to retrieve the "Search Zone", however im unable to perform the search and getText()

I had performed the following on Eclipse but getting error:

**Code:**

```
String HeaderTxt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class = 'number']")).getText();
System.out.println(HeaderTxt);
```

**Error Message:**

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class = 'number']"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have provided to extract the text **Search Zone** you can use the following line of code :

```
String HeaderTxt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-style-abc']/fieldset/legend[(self::legend) and not (@class='number')]")).getText();
System.out.println(HeaderTxt);
```

---

### Update 1

As per your comment update as you are still seeing **NoSuchElementException** possibly you need to wait for the element inducing *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
WebElement HeaderTxtElem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-style-abc']/fieldset/legend[(self::legend) and not (@class='number')]")));
System.out.println(HeaderTxtElem.getText());
```

---

### Update 2

As you mentioned the element is within an `<iframe>` tag you need to switch to the exact *frame* and then look out for the *WebElement*. Here you can find a detailed discussion on [How to switch to frame in Selenium Webdriver Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)

---

### Update 3

### Xpath Explanation

Through the *xpath* as `"//div[@class='form-style-abc']/fieldset/legend"` we have reached till the `<legend>` node. Now you want to get the text **Search Zone** only. So being within the `<legend>` tag you have to trim the child `<span>` tag which have a *class* as **number**. So we added a clause within our *xpath* **not** to consider **(@class='number')** while retrieving the text as in :

```
String HeaderTxt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='form-style-abc']/fieldset/legend[(self::legend) and not (@class='number')]")).getText();
```

Comment: Hi, still getting the following error - no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='form-style-abc']/fieldset/legend[(self::legend) and not (@class='number')]"}

Comment: issue still persist - org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //div[@class='form-style-abc']/fieldset/legend[(self::legend) and not (@class='number')]

Comment: Can you ensure the element is not within an `iframe`?

Comment: Yes, its within the iframe, as such we not be able to get the text?

Comment: Yeap, you need to switch to the exact `iframe` before you start looking out for the element. Check my answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Yes, it worked, after switching to iframe, I'm able to grab the text. Thanks you very much!

Comment: could u pls help to elaborate what does the following portion does, im trying to understand - ..[(self::legend) and not..]

Comment: Check my answer update and let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB!