# How to switch frames through Selenium in Chrome and Firefox browser?

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, firefox, frame

In My case I have Many Frame In The APP Under Test And many popUp So I need Each time  To go Into The Popup And return To original Windows :
**chrome :**

```
ExemplePg.getWindowHandle(); 
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
driver.switchTo().frame(sylobHomepg.get_FrameLevel2());
```

**FireFox:**
 I need to add "defaultContent" with:

```
 ExemplePg.getWindowHandle();
 driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
 driver.switchTo().frame(sylobHomepg.get_FrameLevel2());
```

Questions:

1. Why I have  this difference between chrome and Firefox??
2. My job in Jenkins Work Well, many times and sometimes I have an error: `No such windows`?

Update: With chrome i am using just:

```
ExemplePg.getWindowHandle(); 
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame(sylobHomepg.get_FrameLevel2());
```

Without default and its work and with firefox not I need to add switch default before switch frame.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant *HTML* would have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way as it is still not clear whether you are dealing with `<frame>` / `<iframe>`. Perhaps there is no significant difference between *Chrome* and *Firefox* in handling the `<frame>` / `<iframe>`.

There is no such necessity to `ExemplePg.getWindowHandle();` before switching between `<frame>` / `<iframe>` but it is important to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it* as follows.

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(driver.findElement(sylobHomepg.get_FrameLevel2())));
  ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)

Comment: In my case i am using ExemplePg.getWindowHandle(); to switch between windows as popup