# Selenium can't locate iframe element

Tags: java, selenium, iframe

I want to find the input element in the iframe, however selenium is not able to locate it.

I used both `switchTo().frame(id)` and `switchTo().frame(index)`, but none of it works.

Here is my code:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(id, 'braintree-hosted-field-number')]"));
driver.switchTo().frame(ele);
```

**Error Message:**

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[contains(id, 'braintree-hosted-field-number')]"}
>     (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

**Screenshot:**

[Application HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoItP.png)

Comment: change id to @id or just .

Comment: you should specify the attribute `id` as `@id` in your xpath. If still the iframe not detected then check if it's the another parent iframe by any chance. Btw, it's not a good idea to post the html of screenshot.

Comment: @supputuri sorry, I am pretty new for posting, how should I post the html? Also I used @ id and still not detecting the frame.

Answer (score 3):

Try use `WebDriverWait` with `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt`, like this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("braintree-hosted-field-number")));
```

Following import :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
```

Answer (score 0):

In iframes we can switch with name, id or index

```
driver.switchTo().frame("name or ID");    
driver.switchTo().frame(index);
```

**One frame**- Directly switch to the frame (with the above code)

**Multiple frame** - Switch to the exact frame

**Nested frame** - Switch to the parent frame (*parent frame*) and then switch to the child frame(*inner frame*)

```
driver.switchTo().frame("parent frame");
driver.switchTo().frame("child frame");
```

**Switch to frame with ID or Name** If you have only one iframe then directly switch to the frame otherwise switch to parent frame and then point to the child frame.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("braintree-hosted-field-number");
```

**Switch to frame with index** Seeing your html it looks like there is one iframe and then the index starts with "**0**".
**Example:** If you have 5 iframes then the index will be 0 1 2 3 4

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close. To switch to the desired `<iframe>` you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()`.
- You can use the either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- *xpath*:

  ```
       new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='braintree-hosted-field-number' and contains(@src, 'hosted-fields-frame')]")));
  ```
- *cssSelector*:

  ```
       new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe#braintree-hosted-field-number[src*='hosted-fields-frame']")));
  ```
- Reference: [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)

> Here you can find a detailed discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

By using https://github.com/nick318/FindElementInFrames you can delegate this manual iframe switching and just search the element you need.

```
SearchByFrames searchInFrame = searchFactory.search(() -> driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")));
Optional<WebElement> elem = searchInFrame.getElem();
```

It will look for your element across all available iframes, it works stable and fast.