# Locate element in frame set and frame and div tags using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, frame, frameset

I want to locate the "item1" div tag in the following DOM. I tried in different ways. But I could not make it happen.

```html
<html></html>
<frameset    ... >
<frame>
</frame>
<frame  id= "dynamic value" name = "dynamic value">
<html >
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <div name = "item1">
      <div name = "item2">
```

So , I tried the following ways to locate it. But no such element exception was thrown.

```
driver.getElementsByTagName("frame")[1].getElementsByTagName("div")[0]
driver.swithTo().frame(1);
driver.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]
```

Comment: If any answer helpful the please do accept it so it can be helpful for other. For further queries please feel free to ask. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to frame *before* you search for an element.

Try this:

```
frame = driver.getElementsByTagName("frame")[1]
driver.swithTo().frame(frame);
driver.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]
```

Note, I am not sure what is `getElementsByTagName()`, it looks like some sort of custom method for `findElement()`, so I just copypasted it into my solution from your example.

Answer (score 1):

> **`getElementsByTagName()` DOM method in JavaScript**
>    [Source](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781849515740/1/ch01lvl1sec13/locating-elements-by-tag-name)

Seems like you are using wrong method to locate an element using tag name.

In Selenium Java, Use below code snippet to switch into frame

```
driver.swithTo().frame(1); // index = 1 means 2nd frame
driver.findElements(By.tagName("div"))[0]
```

And with ExplicitWait conditions (to avoid synchronization related issue)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frameName);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you need to consider:

- Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) while dealing with `<iframe>` you can safely ignore the `<frameset>`
- It would be difficult to identify the desired `<iframe>` through their **index** as it will be inconclusive which `<iframe>` loads faster.
- As the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to locate the element you have to:

  - Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()`.
  - Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `visibilityOfElementLocated()`.
- You can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe#dynamicValue[name='dynamicValue']")));
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[name='item1']")));
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='dynamicValue' and @name='dynamicValue']")));
    WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@name='item1']")));
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a coupple of relevant discussions in:

- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)
- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: Thanks. Will refer these links