# Unable to click on a button present in iframe using selenium webdriver and java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on "Continue" Button of below mentioned URL but nothing is working for me. I have tried click() method, Action class and JavaScriptExecuter but nothing is working. Below is the my code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\src\\main\\resources\\All_Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://demo.midtrans.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn buy']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='cart-checkout']")).click();
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.id("snap-midtrans"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='text-button-main']/span")));
//Continue Button
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='text-button-main']/span"));
Actions action  = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(elem, 561, 526).click().build().perform();
driver.quit();
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so to locate the element you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `elementToBeClickable()`.
- You can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe#snap-midtrans")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.text-button-main>span"))).click();
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='snap-midtrans']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Continue']"))).click();
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a coupple of relevant discussions in:

- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)
- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: I have used all the solutions mentioned above but nothing is working for me