# How to click within the username field within ProtonMail signup page using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I'm not able to make it Wright in an username at https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en. For some reason it cant find or cant klick at "choose username", Can any one help me out?

Code trials:

```
public class LaunchApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        int number = 1;


        String url = "https://protonmail.com";
        String password = "passwordpassword123123";
        String username = "";
        String characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        Random rand = new Random();
        int length = 8;





       while (number > 0){

           //Create an random string for the user name:
           // video of how to make string randomicer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZYeTblcOU8 check it out
           char[] text = new char[length];
           for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
               text[i] = characters.charAt(rand.nextInt(characters.length()));
           }

           for(int i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
               username += text[i];
           }
           System.out.println(username);
           Thread.sleep(2000);

           //Program starting: video to make it all work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QY0iQpX0LDU
           driver.get(url);
           System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
           Thread.sleep(2000);

           driver.findElement(By.linkText("SIGN UP")).click();
           Thread.sleep(5000);

           driver.findElement(By.className("panel-heading")).click();
           Thread.sleep(2000);

           driver.findElement(By.id("freePlan")).click();
           Thread.sleep(5000);
           System.out.println("Here");
           Thread.sleep(5000);
           System.out.println("pass1");


           driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
           System.out.println("pass2");
           driver.findElement(By.name("passwordc")).sendKeys(password);
           Thread.sleep(2000);
           System.out.println("Username here");


           try{
               driver.findElement(By.id("username")).click();
           }catch (Exception E){
               System.out.println("DOnt work1");
           }
           try{
               driver.findElement(By.name("username")).click();
           }catch (Exception B){
               System.out.println("DOnt work2");
           }
           try{
               driver.findElement(By.id("input")).click();
           }catch (Exception A){
               System.out.println("DOnt work3");
           }
           try{
               driver.findElement(By.linkText("Choose")).click();
           }catch (Exception A){
               System.out.println("DOnt work4");
           }
           try{
               driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='#username.input']")).click();
           }catch (Exception A){
               System.out.println("DOnt work5");
           }
           try{
               driver.findElement(By.tagName("messages=\"[object Object]\"")).click();
           }catch (Exception A){
               System.out.println("DOnt work6");
           }



           number = number-1;
        }





    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure ProtonMail doesn’t want you to do this.

Comment: Ye probaly not, but its just for learning. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` within the element with placeholder as *Choose username* within the url https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en, as the the desired element is within a `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *cssSelector*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("div.usernameWrap iframe[title='Registration form']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.input#username"))).click();
    ```
  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//div[@class='usernameWrap']//iframe[@title='Registration form']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='input' and @id='username']"))).click();
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: protonmail_username]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)

Comment: Thanks alot!! That workt perfectly!  Im kinda new to Selenium, but i wonna learn it all :)