# Not able to find an element in iframe using Xpath and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am trying to inspect an element in Iframe
I am able to succesfully get into iframe but when trying to inspect element -Exception comes element not intertracble
Below is the html part and the search button I am trying to click
[image]

I tried xpath and inspection like following

```
//driver.findElement(By.className("gsc-search-button-v2")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.gsc-search-button")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='gsc-search-button']")).click();

        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2']")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gsc-search-button.gsc-search-button-v2")).click();

//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2")).click();
//wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".gsc-search-button.gsc-search-button-v2"))).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Also by giving waits also like
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".gsc-search-button.gsc-search-button-v2"))).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

html code
[image]

Comment: Have you tried copying full xpath of the button?

Comment: yes full xpath is the relative xpath that works fine but what if need to create by ourself?for something like <Button class how we are supposed to create xpath?
full xpath is working fine /html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/button

Comment: I think you need to visualize how DOM's tags are organized in order to create the xpath by yourself. Just place the tags separated by slash until you get to the desired element. Notice that some are indexed as td[2] above, which means the button is in the second td tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element to search, as the the desired element is within a `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *cssSelector*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe_cssSelector")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("td.gsc-search-button > button.gsc-search-button.gsc-search-button-v2"))).click();
    ```
  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("iframe_xpath")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='gsc-search-button']/button[@class='gsc-search-button gsc-search-button-v2']"))).click();
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)
- [How to click within the username field within ProtonMail signup page using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62346657/how-to-click-within-the-username-field-within-protonmail-signup-page-using-selen/62349781#62349781)