# How to click on a link inside an iframe which is inside a frame using Selenium Webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I have been trying to automate a few manual checks using **cucumber** and **selenium** and trying to make a click event on a menu item inside a iframe. Below is the skeleton of the source.

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
    <frame src="/XXXX/index.dsp" cd_frame_id_="03af6e390xxxxxxxxx0b209e24f67b9fab">
        <html>
            <body>  
                <iframe class="menuframe" name="menu" src="menu.dsp" scrolling="yes" seamless="seamless">
                    <html>
                    <head>..</head>
                    <body class="menu"...........>
                        <table class="menuTable".............>
                            <tbody>                                         
                                <tr>......</tr>
                                <tr>......</tr>
                                <tr>......</tr>

                                <tr manualhide="true" onclick="toggle(this, 'XXX_subMenu', 'XXXX_twistie');" onmouseover="this.className='cursor';" class="cursor">
                                    <td class="menusection menusection-collapsed" id="elmt_XXXX_subMenu">
                                        <img id="XXXX_twistie" src="/XXXX/images/collapsed_blue.png">
                                          &nbsp;XXXX  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>......</tr>
                                <tr>......</tr>
                            </tbody>
                    </body>
                </iframe>

                <iframe class="contentframe" name="body" id="body" src="stats-general.dsp">
                .............
                </iframe>

            </body>
        </html>
    </frame>
</frameset>
```

I am trying to click on the  above with id elmt_XXXX_subMenu.

As i read in a few blogs it is required to switch to frame. I have tried the following.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
// switch to frame
driver.switchTo().frame(0); 

// switch to menu iframe, It throws an exception
driver.switchTo().frame("menu"); 

// When replaced by following line also it throws same exception
// driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("menu")));
```

Below is the stacktrace.

```
 org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'XXXX', ip: 'XX.XX.XXX.XXX', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 83.0.4103.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\XXXXXX~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:58320}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: f2e850e3e43d7782902297879bc70bc4
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:892)
    at XXX.XXXX.XXXX.pages.TestPage.test(TestPage.java:40)
    at XXX.XXXX.XXXX.stepdefinitions.TestSteps.test_method(TestSteps.java:137)
    at ?.Then Check menu(basicChecks.feature:12)
```

Kindly suggest if it is not the right way to do it?
Many thanks in advance.

**Update:**
As Per @DebanjanB answer, Tried using suggested snippet(both css selector and xpath),

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("frame[src*='index']")));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.menuframe[name='menu']")));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("td.menusection.menusection-collapsed#elmt_XXXX_subMenu"))).click();
```

Throws same exception at line 2

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'XXXX', ip: 'XX.XX.XXX.XXX', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 83.0.4103.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\XXXXXX~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:58320}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 79f14698ee49ff2f4308b7f7930ee8b1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:892)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$17.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:501)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$17.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:497)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:249)
    at XXX.XXXX.XXXX.pages.TestPage.test(TestPage.java:26)
    at XXX.XXXX.XXXX.stepdefinitions.TestSteps.test_method(TestSteps.java:137)
    at ?.Then Check menu(basicChecks.feature:12)
```

Comment: The second `</iframe>` closing tag was never started within `<body>`. Cross check the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get get it working by switching content by index. Using `System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());` to log page source to console and make sure i am working at the right spot.
I tried to find iframes by tag and print their name as following.

```
List<WebElement> elements = DriverContext.driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
elements.forEach(element -> System.out.println(element.getAttribute("name"))); // printed 'menu' and 'body', perfect
```

But, while switching content to iframe using name, tried also using WebDriverWait,

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("menu")));
```

for whatever reason, it didn't work and kept throwing the exception as in the question.

Using index to switch to iframe followed by click on the element worked.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0); // switch to frame
driver.switchTo().frame(0); // switch to first iframe

driver.findElement(By.id("elmt_XXXX_subMenu")).click();
```

Also, i had used WebDriverWait to wait for page load.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete"));
```

Answer (score 1):

To `click()` on the element within the `<iframe>` which is within a `<frame>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the first *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the second *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *cssSelector*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("frame[src*='index']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.menuframe[name='menu']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("td.menusection.menusection-collapsed#elmt_XXXX_subMenu"))).click();
    ```
  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//frame[contains(@src, 'index')]")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='menuframe' and @name='menu']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='menusection menusection-collapsed' and @id='elmt_XXXX_subMenu']"))).click();
    ```

> **Note**: As per the current HTML you have provided the following `<iframe>` looks to be closed which may not be true:

```
<iframe class="menuframe" name="menu" src="menu.dsp" scrolling="yes" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer. Sorry that there was a mistake while writing html skeleton in the question. I just updated it.
Using css selector and xpath, I get same exception in the second line (stacktrace in the question).

new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.menuframe[name='menu']")));

Log:
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Comment: @NagarajaJB Instead of the hand crafted HTML can you update the question with the text based actual HTML please?

Comment: I was able to get it working using index again to switch to iframe. Many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`.frame()` is used to switch the element to an `iframe` and it takes an element as its parameter, so you need to pass the element there. Also, element with "0" is not a type of iframe, so you don't need the `driver.switchTo().frame(0)` line of code.

You just need switch the driver to the `menu` iframe and then click on the element.

For switching to the `menu` iframe you need to use:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("menu")));
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.
I get below org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException if i try to switch to the iframe directly. I tried adding WebDriverWait also.

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name='menu']"}

If i switch to frame and try, then exception as in the question.