# How to get total number of nested frames inside the frame

Tags: selenium, nested, webdriverwait, frames, expected-condition

Snapshot of Frame_top with 3 nested frames:

[image: Frame_top with 3 nested frames]

Code:

```
WebElement topframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='frame-top']"));   
String frame1 =  driver.switchTo().frame(topframe).switchTo().frame("frame-left").findElement(By.xpath("//body")).getText();                
System.out.println(frame1);
List<WebElement> nestedFrames = driver.switchTo().frame(topframe).findElements(By.tagName("frame"));
System.out.println(nestedFrames.size());
```

On top you can see this page has nested frames inside the frame(frame_top).
Using line 1-3 I'm able to get the text of each nested frame.  However I can't get number of frames inside the "Frame_top".(Line 4-5).
How do I get total number of frames inside the "frame_top"?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get total number of nested *frames* with in the parent `<frame>` you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()* of the *frames*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *cssSelector* and *tagName*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("frame[name='frame-top']")));
    System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.tagName("frame"))).size());
    ```
  - Using *xpath* and *tagName*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//frame[@name='frame-top']")));
    System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.tagName("frame"))).size());
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c://chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver d=new ChromeDriver();
    d.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/");
    d.findElement(By.linkText("Nested Frames")).click();
    System.out.println("Pareent Frames Are "+d.findElements(By.tagName("frame")).size()+" in this Web Page");
    int parentFrames=d.findElements(By.tagName("frame")).size();
    d.switchTo().frame("frame-top");
    System.out.println("Child Frames are "+d.findElements(By.tagName("frame")).size()+" in the Web Page");
    int childFrames=d.findElements(By.tagName("frame")).size();
    d.switchTo().frame("frame-middle");
    System.out.println(d.findElement(By.id("content")).getText());
    System.out.println("Total Number of Frames are "+(parentFrames+childFrames));
    d.quit();
}
```

Comment: If you add some explanations to your code, it will make your code more understandable