# How to enter text with in the chat bot form input fields of https://www.phptravels.net/home using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, chatbot, webdriverwait

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class Bot {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        WebDriver driver;
        String baseURL = "https://www.phptravels.net/";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/khawar/workspace/MyTest/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseURL);
        List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@id = 'chat-widget']"));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        if(element.size()>0){
            element.get(0).click();
        }
        driver.switchTo().frame(1);
        // Enter Name
        driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("reretr");
        // Enter Phone Number
        driver.findElement(By.id("o68vveqb3d_157907312787606648")).sendkeys("1234567");
        // Enter Email
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
        // Click on button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pvtkmhumbra']/div/form/div[7]/button/div/span")).click();

    }

}
```

When I click on Chat Bot icon, it is opened. But I try to enter values by using sendkey then they are not entered into input fields. Any suggestion plz? I don't know what is going wrong with that. Please let me know how I can give input to those fields?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`driver.switchTo().frame(1);`

use

`driver.switchTo().frame("chat-widget")`

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

To send the *character sequences* within the desired fields of the url https://www.phptravels.net/home, as the the desired elements are within a `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
  options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
  options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
  WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/home");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='chat-widget']")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Open LiveChat chat widget']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='name']"))).sendKeys("reretr");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label/span[text()='WhatsApp Number:']//following::input[1]")).sendKeys("1234567");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Start the chat']")).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: PHPTRAVELLS_CHAT]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)