# Cannot click input type submit navgation using Selenium Webdriver with java client

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Open http://www.canadapostsurvey.ca/, try to locate the "Next" navigation button click or submit it using xpath or cssselector or other method but does not work.
(updates: found an alternative solution not using any find element methods but would like to hear from others)

Have tried different locator properties but none of it works, any ideas?

```
new  WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nav-controls\"]/input")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"nav-controls\"]/input")).click();`
```

html code:

```
<div id="nav-controls" class="btn-container nav-center">
<input type="submit" name="_NNext" class="mrNext" style="" value="Next" alt="Next">
</div>
```

Screenshot of the page:

[image: screenshot of the page]

Answer (score 0):

The button is in a frame so switch to the frame("mainFrame") first then click on the button.

You can use below code to achieve the same.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\test\\resources\\executables\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.canadapostsurvey.ca/");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-controls']/input")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav-controls']/input")).click();;
    driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` within the element with placeholder as *Choose username* within the url https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en, as the the desired element is within a `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *cssSelector*:

    ```
    driver.get("http://www.canadapostsurvey.ca/");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("frame#mainFrame")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[value='Next']"))).click();
    ```
  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    driver.get("http://www.canadapostsurvey.ca/");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//frame[@id='mainFrame']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@value='Next']"))).click();
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)