# Is there any solution to bypass the cookie iframe by using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I have an issue to accept a cookie alert on the below website which is embedded in an iframe:

https://www.hamburg.de/

[image]

I've tried many ways to solve the issue with using the `driver.switchTo().frame()` - method:

- by using the Id of the iframe `sp_message_iframe_234327`
- by inserting an index for the iframe `0`
- by calling the iframe through a WebElement  `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[6]/iframe[@src='https://cdn.privacy-mgmt.com/index.html?message_id=234327&consentUUID=b2cb90ea-dfdd-4655-b6b9-89117ff34893&requestUUID=ccb96546-c6b5-44e7-9869-438b32f7ad89&preload_message=true']")); driver.switchTo().frame(element);`

Unfortunately none of them are working. I'm always getting the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException
```

Does anyone have an idea on this specific example to switch on the iframe properly?
I'm working with Selenium WebDriver 3.141.59 on Java and my tests should be executed on Mozilla Firefox (80.0.1) and Chromium (85.0.4183.102). Those two browsers are launched headlessly.
Glad for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on <kbd>Alle akzeptieren</kbd> within the url https://www.hamburg.de/, as the the desired element is within a `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *cssSelector*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.hamburg.de/");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[id^='sp_message_iframe']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[aria-label='Alle akzeptieren']"))).click();
    ```
  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.hamburg.de/");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'sp_message_iframe')]")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Alle akzeptieren']"))).click();
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: hamburg_de]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)