# Selenium couldn't find iframe using its id (Java)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, iframe, ui-automation

I am working on the task from 'Automation on Java' course.
In scope of this task I need to create a test which should interact with elements from this page https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator
I need to create a script which will fill some specific fields from this page.

As I can see there are few iframes on this page.
First of all, I need to fill the 'Number of instances' field.
I see that element which I am interested in (//input[@id='input_90']) is located inside the iframe (id = 'myFrame').

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz8qc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEoBV.png)

Based on that, I create a method, which should switch me to this iframe using its id value:

```
    public void switchFrameToMyFrame() {
        driver.switchTo().frame("myFrame");
    }
```

But when I am trying to run this specific test

```
@Test
    @Order(2)
    @DisplayName("Fill Calculation Form")
    public void fillCalculationForm() {
        driver.get("https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator");
        pricingCalculatorPage.switchFrameToMyFrame();
```

I am getting this error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id myFrame
```

I tried several approaches how I can swich to another frame:

```
//using if value of the iframe
driver.switchTo().frame("myFrame");

//using xpath of the element inside the iframe
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='input_90']")));

//I tried to add this row in case if my test ends before the page iframe is loaded on the page
fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(myFrame));

//I even tried to create a method which should find the index of the iframe using its id, but seems like it found the wrong index. After I switched to iframe using the index value which I got from this method, driver was not able to find the element inside the iframe. It could be because of the iframe index is wrong
public void findIframeIndex() {
        int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            driver.switchTo().frame(i);
            int total = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='myFrame']")).size();
            System.out.println(total);
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        }
    }
```

I've read a lot of information about how I can deal with iframes but I didn't found what I need to do in my specific case.

Could anyone help me to understand how I can interact at least with the 'Number of instances' field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 iframes (nested iframes), '`Number of instances`', and other associated fields inside the second iframe. So you have to switch to the outer iframe and then inner iframe, try the below code:

imports:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));
    
driver.get("https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator");
    
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));

// switch to the first iframe
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath(".//*[starts-with(@name,'goog_')]")));
    
// switch to the second iframe
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("myFrame")));
        
driver.findElement(By.id("input_90")).sendKeys("56");
```

After entering all the values, you can switch to the first iframe using:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is within nested [*iframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the first [*frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63831871/7429447).
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the second [*frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472200/7429447).
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired [*elementToBeClickable*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447).
- You can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  import java.time.Duration;
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  driver.get("https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator");
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[src^='https://cloud.google.com/frame/products/calculator']")));
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("myFrame")));
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model='listingCtrl.computeServer.quantity' and @aria-label='quantity' and @name='quantity']"))).sendKeys("4");
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: multipleFrame]