# Message: javascript error: Cannot set properties of null setting 'innerHTML' in Selenium 4.7.2 using Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, innerhtml

Tried to execute this script in selenium Python 4.7.2 with this line of code:

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector(".ck-placeholder").innerHTML = "TEST";')
```

I have checked DevTools, and the element does exist.

When running the code over this error appears:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
```

---

I am trying to make a automatic messager bot that sends messages in Microsoft Teams via Selenium Python. I do know that there are other ways to send messages via apis, eg. but I want to learn Seleneium via this project.

The element: `.ck-placeholder` is the input field of Microsoft Teams (Messaging).

Here is the GitHub: https://github.com/LucasoDevDotTk/automatic_login_microsoft, send_msg.py is the file I'm working on

**Expected results**:
innerHTML of `.ck-placeholder` to be replaced with "TEST"

**Possible Causes**: I havent checked if this is correct but `.ck-placeholder` is placed in an iframe, may this be the issue?

[image: Picture of the iframe in devtools]

Comment: Even though the element exists, often in integration testing using frameworks like Selenium, you have to wait until the test has loaded the component prior to accesing it's properties. So although the page has it, the test at that point of execution may not have it loaded. Can you paste the entire script?

Comment: I have just added a link to the GitHub repository :)

Comment: If you are looking how to improve a Stack Overflow question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is within an [*iframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so first you have to induce [*WebDriverWait*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the [*frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63831871/7429447) as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.embedded-electron-webview.embedded-page-content")))
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector(".ck-placeholder").innerHTML = "TEST";')
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```