# Selenium can't find iframe after postback inside the iframe after finding one element inside the frame

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am trying to create a test where I have to fill out some information inside an iframe. Getting access to the iframe work fine and I can fill out information inside the frame. The issue is that when I find out a element 'A' it has a postback attached to it which reloads the content inside the iframe, to find out another element 'B'. So i am not able to find that element.I am getting below error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <iframe style="overflow-x:hidden;" id="t5" height="1350" frameborder="0" width="98%" src="https://edata.ndtv.com/coronavirus/table/india_table.html?shgraph=1&amp;days=7" cd_frame_id_="7da8f2aea5a580b3a6e90a9d5016fa0d">...</iframe> is not clickable at point (554, 7). Other element would receive the click: <div class="topnav2014" style="border-bottom: none;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
```

Here are my observations: When I first locate the iframe it looks like this:

```
<iframe style="overflow-x:hidden;" id="t5" height="1350" frameborder="0" width="98%" src="https://edata.ndtv.com/coronavirus/table/india_table.html?shgraph=1&amp;days=7">
```

After the postback has occurred it looks like this:

```
<iframe style="overflow-x:hidden;" id="t5" height="1350" frameborder="0" width="98%" src="https://edata.ndtv.com/coronavirus/table/india_table.html?shgraph=1&amp;days=7" cd_frame_id_="a5006acf28d8c288313681ab9ad7a4fa">
```

I can easily find element A:

But element B i am not able to find
The code fails when I try to get hold of the iframe element.

How can I get hold of the iframe again, after the postback inside the frame?

I have tried this suggestion also but it is not working

```
//Ensure that you are back to the base frame  
driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
//SwitchTo the intended frame
 driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'<removed for clearity>')]")));
```

Comment: if you can mention the steps to reproduce this with target url.

Comment: `Element ... is not clickable at point (554, 7)` means that you are able to find element, but you are not able to click it because another element overlap it. It can be popup or you need to scroll to your element. Also you can try to click using js.

Comment: I still don't see the postback you mentioned within the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DilipMeghwal   This is the url i am trying: https://www.ndtv.com/coronavirus/india-covid-19-tracker----In this i am trying to automate i need to take state wise active cases. So for state wise active cases there are two xpath:                                 
 private By TotalTodayActiveCasesforStatesDown=By.xpath("//tr//td[3]//p//span[@class='data-down']"); private By TotalTodayActiveCasesforStatesUp=By.xpath("//tr//td[3]//p//span[@class='data-up']");

Comment: @AliaksandrPlekhau: I tried with javascript also its not working

Comment: @DebanjanB: There are two elements:private By TotalTodayActiveCasesforStatesDown=By.xpath("//tr//td[3]//p//span[@class='data-down']"); private By TotalTodayActiveCasesforStatesUp=By.xpath("//tr//td[3]//p//span[@class='data-up']");      When i try to click on second element its comes out of frame. Also when i am reopening the browser it is working fine. Please see the code below:

Comment: List<WebElement> elementsd = ct.TotalTodayActiveCasesforStatesDown();
  for (WebElement element : elementsd) {
   String text= element.getText();
   System.out.println(text);
   String TotalTodayStateCasedown=text.split("\\r?\\n")[0];
   System.out.println(TotalTodayStateCasedown);
   
elementssd = ct.TotalTodayActiveCasesforStatesUp();
for (WebElement element : elementssd) {String text= element.getText();System.out.println(text);

Comment: @ManaliMalkani Could you share all your code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use a driver.executescript() for the first problem since another element is receiving the click.

```
element = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <iframe style="overflow-x:hidden;" id="t5" height="1350" frameborder="0" width="98%" src="https://edata.ndtv.com/coronavirus/table/india_table.html?shgraph=1&amp;days=7" cd_frame_id_="7da8f2aea5a580b3a6e90a9d5016fa0d">...</iframe> is not clickable at point (554, 7). Other element would receive the click: <div class="topnav2014" style="border-bottom: none;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)
```

...implies that the *WebDriverException* was raised as you tried to invoke `click()` on the `<iframe>` element.

Factually, instead of clicking on the `<iframe>` element you would invoke `click()` on an element within the `<iframe>`. Moreover, as the the desired element is within a `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe_xpath")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("element_xpath"))).click();
    ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to extract the data of the active cases rise and fall for every state. There is a single frame which contains both the locators shared by you. Check below working code.

```
    driver.get("https://www.ndtv.com/coronavirus");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("tab-wrapper")));
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://edata.ndtv.com/coronavirus/table/india_table.html?shgraph=1')]")));
    
    //cases down
    List<WebElement> eleCasesUp = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr//td[3]//p//span[@class='data-up']"));
    List<String> casesUpList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (WebElement element : eleCasesUp) { 
        casesUpList.add(element.getText()); 
    }
    
    //cases up
    List<WebElement> eleCasesDown = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr//td[3]//p//span[@class='data-down']"));
    List<String> casesDownList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (WebElement element : eleCasesDown) { 
        casesDownList.add(element.getText()); 
    }
    
    System.out.println("Cases Up List -->" + casesUpList);
    System.out.println("Cases Down List -->" + casesDownList);
```