# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: no such frame using Selenium + Java + Chromedriver in Docker with Centos 7

Tags: java, linux, docker, selenium, centos7

I have a test that executed in my windows machine works fine but now im trying to make it works in a docker with centos 7, java version 1.8.0_272, chrome and chromedriver 87.0 but it just dont works, this what the stacktrace says:

```
    Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0b2a448e658c0dbd8311fb04ddbd-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#355}) on port 23699
All remote connections are allowed. Use an allowlist instead!
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[main] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer - Starting proxy at address: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:0
[main] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer - Proxy listening with TCP transport
[main] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer - Proxy started at address: /0.0.0.0:34162
Nov 30, 2020 2:12:27 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: no such frame
  (Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.66)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'b3782858cd26', ip: 'xxx.xx.x.x', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_272'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 87.0.4280.66, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.Tp1C2S}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:39255}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=proxy.cl..., setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 8b9b8ef4dd9b0e870d8974c6f3b38e47
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:872)
        at seleniumjavapqr.pqrMovil.pqrMovilRegistrar(pqrMovil.java:30)
        at seleniumjavapqr.myDriver.main(myDriver.java:128)
[LittleProxy-JVM-shutdown-hook] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer - Shutting down proxy server immediately (non-graceful)
[LittleProxy-JVM-shutdown-hook] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer - Closing all channels (non-graceful)
[LittleProxy-JVM-shutdown-hook] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.ServerGroup - Shutting down server group event loops (non-graceful)
[LittleProxy-JVM-shutdown-hook] INFO org.littleshoot.proxy.impl.DefaultHttpProxyServer - Done shutting down proxy server
```

In the line `seleniumjavapqr.pqrMovil.pqrMovilRegistrar(pqrMovil.java:30)` my code says:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

I don't know how important it is, but, in the stacktrace line 12 where expect to be the selenium info there's just 'unknown'

As important information i can say that i import selenium-server-standalone.1.141.59.jar as a library in my test jar and again, i don't know if this is ok.

Comment: Yes, I did it. I have a working app which is running in docker, grabbing data via chrome driver. Which base image you are using?
I used this:

FROM markhobson/maven-chrome:jdk-11

Comment: I use FROM centos:7 and there inside install chrome and java, i'm gonna try with yours

Comment: Start your jar inside the container with something like this:
if [ -z "$BROKERHOST" ] ; then BROKERHOST=`ip route | grep default | cut -d ' ' -f 3` ; echo "[I] BROKERHOST was not set. determined: $BROKERHOST" ; fi; brokerUrl="tcp://${BROKERHOST}:${BROKERPORT:-61616}"; java -jar -Dspring.activemq.broker-url=${brokerUrl} -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver YOURJAR.jar

Comment: `172.17.0.1 [I] BROKERHOST was not set. determined: ` it was the answer

Comment: And you used the same image I proposed (**markhobson/maven-chrome:jdk-11**)? What happend if your start you image with **docker run -it IMAGE /bin/sh** and then type **ip route**? Which network mode you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of switching within the `<iframe>` using an *index* as:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Ideally, you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *frameName*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.name("frame_name")));
  ```
- Switch *frameID*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("frame_id")));
  ```
- Using *frameCssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("frame_cssSelector")));
  ```
- Using *frameXpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("frame_xpath")));
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)