# Selenium StaleElementReferenceException after frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt

Tags: java, selenium, staleelementreferenceexception

If Selenium throws a StaleElementReferenceException it is usually (?) because the state of web page (DOM) Selenium "owns" has changed due to outside interference but I started to get it when I added `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt` before a `switch` statement. My code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpDownArrow)).click();
WebElement iframeElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpIframe));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath(xpIframe)));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframeElement);
```

Originally my code consisted just of line 1, 2 and 4, which worked most of the time but failed 10-20 % of the executions, and I therefore added line 2 but now I get the `StaleElementReferenceException` everytime this code executes. I don't get that. Why would line 3 change the DOM? Isn't this the recommended way to perform a `switch`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of those smaller redundant steps you can *switch* to the desired `<iframe>` inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) using an [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) optimally as follows:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("xpIframe")));
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)

Answer (score 0):

With line 3

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath(xpIframe)));
```

you've already switched to iframe. So line 4 is not needed- it just trying to perform switching to the same frame. Try to remove it (line 2 is also redundant)