# Automation: How to click on div role="radio" with only aria-label identifier?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I have the following code written in Java with Selenium Webdriver, but it's not clicking the div with the star rating

```
driver.get("https://goo.gl/maps/gLCX3PitJT1cXr9v9");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-value=\"Escribir una opinión\"]")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame(2);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea")).sendKeys("This is just a test");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@aria-label=\"Cuatro estrellas\"]")).click();
```

Between each line, I also added a Thread.sleep(5000) just to ensure the page fully loads.

The only clear identifier that I see is the aria-label.

[image: Full HTML]

Manual steps:

- Open URL: https://goo.gl/maps/gLCX3PitJT1cXr9v9
- Click "Escribir una opinión" or "Write a review" button
- Type in the review field: "This is just a test"
- Select the star rating: 4 stars
- Click "Publicar" or "Post" (or Publish)

Comment: Can update the question with the manual steps we need to perform to reach to the desired HTML?

Comment: @DebanjanB done, it's basically the same from the code

Comment: At which step are you stuck and need help?

Comment: @DebanjanB see the description: "it's not clicking the div with the star rating"

Answer (score 0):

The Xpath for the "four-star" element is wrong. It should be `//div[@aria-label='Cuatro estrellas']`. You had `span` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class="s2xyy"][4]")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@role="radio"][3]")).click();
```

it is working for me
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To [click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770992/how-many-ways-to-click-on-webelement-in-webdriver/70077251#70077251) on star rating ***4*** stars as the the desired element is within a `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *cssSelector*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.goog-reviews-write-widget")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div[aria-label='Four stars']"))).click();
    ```
  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='goog-reviews-write-widget']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Four stars']"))).click();
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)