# Drag and drop not working in unlayer web site

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I have performed drag and drop on unlayer web site and all positive combination I have used. but drap and drop not working.

We have tried following code with selenium 4.

```
@Test()
     public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get("https://dashboard.unlayer.com/create/blank?_gl=1*afclpx*_ga*NzU0NTMwNzU3LjE2NzYzMTAyOTk.*_ga_VMP9QH8KW8*MTY3NjMxMDI5OC4xLjEuMTY3NjMxMDMwOS41OC4wLjA.");
        Thread.sleep(9000);
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        
        Thread.sleep(9000);
        
                //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div [text ()='Text']"));
        
        WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div [text ()='Text']"));
        
        //source.click();
        
        Thread.sleep(9000);
        WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='No content here. Drag content from right.']"));
        System.out.println("target");
        System.out.println("target= "+target.getText());
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
          Actions a = new Actions(driver); 
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          //a.clickAndHold(source).moveToElement(target).release().build().perform();
          //a.clickAndHold(target);
          //a.dragAndDrop(source, target);
          //a.moveToElement(target);
          a.click(source);
          System.out.println("Click on="+"source");
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          a.release(target);
          a.click(target);
          System.out.println("Click on="+"target");
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472200/7429447). So to perform *Drag and Drop* you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890): solutions:

  - Using *`dragAndDrop()`* method:

    ```
    driver.get("https://dashboard.unlayer.com/create/blank?_gl=1afclpx_gaNzU0NTMwNzU3LjE2NzYzMTAyOTk._ga_VMP9QH8KW8*MTY3NjMxMDI5OC4xLjEuMTY3NjMxMDMwOS41OC4wLjA.");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[data-tid='banner-accept']"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[src*='https://editor.unlayer.com']")));
    Thread.sleep(10);
    WebElement dragMe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='blockbuilder-content-tool' and @draggable='true']//div[text()='Text']"));
    WebElement dropHere = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='No content here. Drag content from right.']"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.dragAndDrop(dragMe, dropHere).build().perform();
    ```
  - Using *`clickAndHold().moveToElement().release()`* methods:

    ```
    driver.get("https://dashboard.unlayer.com/create/blank?_gl=1afclpx_gaNzU0NTMwNzU3LjE2NzYzMTAyOTk._ga_VMP9QH8KW8*MTY3NjMxMDI5OC4xLjEuMTY3NjMxMDMwOS41OC4wLjA.");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button[data-tid='banner-accept']"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[src*='https://editor.unlayer.com']")));
    Thread.sleep(10);
    WebElement drag = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='blockbuilder-content-tool' and @draggable='true']//div[text()='Text']"));
    WebElement drop = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='No content here. Drag content from right.']"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.clickAndHold(drag).moveToElement(drop).release(drop).build().perform();
    ```

Comment: Thanks for solutions. but code is not working properly, 

Given this Error.
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument: uniqueContextId not found
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.120)
Build info: version: '4.8.0', revision: '267030adea'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.3'

Comment: I have run both code.
But drap and drop not working on browser.

Comment: @NirbhayDeep There was a bug in the code which I have corrected now. Retest and let me know the status.

Comment: In First Code [dragAndDrop()] Code run fine and test case also pass. But drag and drop feature not working.

Comment: How about the `clickAndHold().moveToElement().release()` method?

Comment: In First Code [dragAndDrop()] Code run fine and test case also pass. But drag and drop feature not working.

In Second Code - Same Exception is accruing.

Comment: Anyone can help about this code. Code is running but action is not performed.

Using HTML 5.

Comment: any one can provide solutions?