# How to click element within multiple nested iframe using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

While clickig the element inside the iframe getting selenium timeout of *no such frame element* exception . It's the [RedBus web application](https://www.redbus.in/) I am using.

I tried with the driver switch to ().the frame("gsi_934517_585705"); with id, Name, index too but no success.

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.redbus.in/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='signin-block']")).click();      
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='signInLink' and text()='Sign In/Sign Up']")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(2000));
//Thread.sleep(50000);
driver.switchTo().frame("gsi_934517_585705");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Sign in with Google' and @class='nsm7Bb-HzV7m-LgbsSe-BPrWId']")).click();
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below line of code won't switch to the required iframe because the ID is dynamic and each time you execute, the iframe id is different.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("gsi_934517_585705");
```

Try the below code:

```
driver.get("https://www.redbus.in/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='signin-block']")).click();      
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='signInLink' and text()='Sign In/Sign 
    Up']")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
//System.out.println("no of iframes" + size);
//There are 2 iframes,we are interested in the second one,hence the below line
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Sign in with Google' and @class='nsm7Bb-HzV7m-LgbsSe-BPrWId']")).click();
driver.close();
```

Basically, get the number of iframes and switch to the iframe you want based on its index. Good luck. Upvote if this answers and solves your query,

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element <kbd>Sign in with Google</kbd> as the the desired element is within nested [*iframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the parent [*frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51621710/7429447).
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63831871/7429447) for the nested [*frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51621710/7429447).
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621712/7429447) for the desired [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447).
- You can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.redbus.in/");
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#signin-block"))).click();
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("ul.config-list > li#signInLink"))).click();
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.modalIframe")));
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='Sign in with Google Button']")));
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Sign in with Google']"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: RedBus_SignIn_Google]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472200/7429447)
- [Is there any solution to bypass the cookie iframe by using selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63831871/7429447)