# PHP WebDriver cant select iframe for login

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe

I am making script that will login to "https://asia.nikkei.com/". The script opens the login window which is in a iframe.

But then iam not able to select `<inputs>` for email and password. And when I try to switchTo iframe with id "piano-id-AciFE", I'm getting "no such frame" error using this code:

```
$driver->switchTo()->frame("piano-id-AciFE");
```

I tried another solution with:

```
$username = $driver->switchTo()->activeElement();
```

after the login window open, but this solution doesnt work either.

Is there any way to select login input in this case?

Comment: Are you sure that page doesn't have any protection against being loaded in an iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the *id* attribute is partially static (i.e. *`piano-id-`*) and partially dynamic (i.e. *`AciFE`*). When I access the [website](https://asia.nikkei.com/#) I find the value of the *id* attribute as ***piano-id-IE9ZK***

In such cases to switch to the desired [*iframe*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) you can refer to the **preceeding(*sibling*)** [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *xpath* and *`following`*:

  ```
  $element = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//button[@aria-label='Close']//following::iframe[1]"));
  $driver->switchTo()->frame(element);
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *`following-sibling`*:

  ```
  $element = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//button[@aria-label='Close']//following-sibling::iframe[1]"));
  $driver->switchTo()->frame(element);
  ```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [WebDriver - How to locate iframe without id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71180539/7429447)