# How to switch to a different driver url after login in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

After logging in i want to locate element on home page and want a click on that but unfortunately it is unable to find element because of driver as it contains url of login.
How can i switch to different driver on same page.

```
 public void home()
  {

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  

        driver.get("https://localhost:8443/ablogin");

        driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys("superadmin@ab.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys("admin");
        driver.findElement(By.ByClassName.className("btn")).click();
       //Home Page Opened 
       driver.findElement(By.linkText("settings")).click();
       driver.close();
       System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Comment: "switch to different driver" is entirely a different concept. I believe you can apply a simpler solution by identifying the "settings" link correctly. Can you please share the HTML snippet (with a few levels of ancestors) of the element that you wish to identify.

Comment: @Dharam   <li sec:authorize="hasRole('Setting Page')">
              <a th:href="@{/settings}">Settings</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

Comment: Prasoon, After clicking on 'Settings' link, Is it opening new settings page in new window ? In that case, you might need to check switching between windows concept of selenium webdriver. Check this out : http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/

Comment: nope you didnt get it correctly. i am unable to open settings page as it is unable to find the settings locator

Comment: Can you please post the html code for the settings element which you are unable to find?

Comment: @debugger89-   <li sec:authorize="hasRole('Setting Page')">
              <a th:href="@{/settings}">Settings</a>
            </li>

Comment: @debugger89  Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS Selector :
`li[sec:authorize*='Setting Page']>a[th:href$='settings}']`

Comment: tried this way but not working                                                                                       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[sec:authorize*='Setting Page']>a[th:href$='settings}']")).click();

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: `li[sec\:authorize*='Setting Page']>a[th\:href$='settings}']` - You need to escape the colon in the selector

Comment: same error tried like this.    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[sec\':authorize*='Setting Page']>a[th\':href$='settings}']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple scenarios where you cannot identify an element.

**Invalid locator**

One issue i can see in your locator is in the line :  `driver.findElement(By.linkText("settings")).click();`

Here you have used the link text "settings" (notice the 's' is simple) as locator. But in your HTML code the settings link the settings link's S is capital. 
You have to use the exact link text in HTML.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Settings")).click();
```

**Page Load Time**

Another reason for the failure might be is the page load time out. Soon after navigating to the home page you are trying to find the settings link which might not be not loaded yet. So give ample time after page navigation for the page to load.

```
driver.findElement(By.ByClassName.className("btn")).click();
//Home Page Opened 
// Wait till page is loaded properly before continue.
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("settings")).click();
```

**Iframes**

The settings link might be inside an iframe. Check your html code for any iframe. If the link is in an iframe you have to switch to that before finding an element inside it.

```
driver.switchTo().frame()
```

See the following answer explaining how to switch to iframes in Selenium. 
[how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10887059/3091196)

Comment: Rather than using a shotgun approach and answering every question the OP might need... please ask for clarification before answering. It will be more likely to actually answer the question asked.