# How to fix iframes not working with Microsoft Edge?

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe, webdriver, microsoft-edge

Change iframe works fine with Firefox webdriver and Chrome web driver but not with the Microsoft Edge Driver. All the other tests are working fine in Edge, but not changing iframes. I updated the Edge driver and Windows 10 because it's a known issue, but this still has not resolved my problem. Is there any other way to fix this?

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
driver.switchTo().frame("settingiframe");
driver.findElement(By.id("LibraryConfigurations")).click();
```

Out come message will be : no such element found

Comment: check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: Code is working on normal browsers but not in edge...

Comment: I suggest, first try finding frame element and then try switching to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `WebDriverWait` to wait for frame available then switch like as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("settingiframe")); 

//after successfully switching to frame you need to wait until element to be clickable
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("LibraryConfigurations")));
el.click();
```

**Note** :- The above code will `wait` for a given `frame` **up to 20 seconds**. If the `frame` will be available within given time, it will switch to the given `frame`. Otherwise, it will throw `TimeoutException`.

Hope it will help you...:)