# Unable to locate elements through Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium

Page source Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
 </head><script>var _AdfWindowOpenError='A popup window blocker has been detected in your browser. Popup blockers interfere with the operation of this application. Please disable your popup blocker or allow popups from this site.';</script>
<script src="/dc4custmanager/adf/jsLibs/Common10_1_3_4_0.js">  </script><script language="javascript">document.onkeydown=_noReload;var _blockReload=1;function _fixDialogTitle(){window.document.title=window.frames[0].document.title};</script>
<frameset title="Content" rows="100%,*" onload="_fixDialogTitle(); _sizeWin(window.frames[0],0,30)" onunload="_checkUnload(event)">
  <frame title="Content" frameborder="0" noresize src="/dc4custmanager/faces/view/edi/editEdiInfo.jsp?_afPfm=1.2&loc=en" longdesc="#">
  <noframes>Your browser does not support frames. Frames support is required for this functionality</noframes>
```

I am able to locate elements through Firefox IDE. But I am unable to locate element through webdriver. Here I m using chrome. Please help me out in order to locate elements?

Comment: Which element are you trying to locate, what xpath/css selector you are have tried so far?

Also you could format you code so it would be more readable. Select the code and click '{}' from formatting toolbar

Answer (score 0):

From your page source code, its clear that your element supposed to be in frame.

Before locating element inside frame/iframe first switch to its frame.

```
 driver.switchTo().frame()
```

More Details:
[How to switch frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)