# I cannot click on continue button nor exit button and proceed to next page

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have tried everything. I am unable to track also.

```
<button accesskey="c" id="Continue" class="jfabtn" type="button" onclick="submitForm()"><u>C</u>ontinue</button>
```

My code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Continue")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=Continue]");
```

­

```
<button accesskey="x" id="Exit" class="jfabtn" type="button" onclick="exit()">E<u>x</u>it</button>
```

My code

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Exit")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=Exit]");
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit about *I cannot click*? Did you get any exception?

Comment: As you are not mentioning any error here, so i am assuming that by executing above code, you won't get any error, so try to click on button element using `javascript-Executor` Method. For more details on this issue, refer my answer below.

Comment: You need to check for a frame. If there is any frame present then you need to switch to frame first..

Comment: refer :- https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html

Comment: refer :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: What error are you getting? My guess is that it's either in an iframe that you need to switch to or it's a case where you need a wait. Try both of those and report back if anything worked or post the additional error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click on button using `javascript-Executor` Method.

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("Continue"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Continue);
```

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's work for you.

Answer (score -2):

Please try this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//**Enter here class name of that element**[contains(@id,'Exit')]")).click();
```

Comment: Why OP should *enter class name of that element* instead of node name? Why specifying partial `id` value is better than specifying exact `id`?