# How to click on a link in an iFrame in selenium IDE

Tags: html, selenium, iframe, selenium-ide

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I am working with selenium IDE and I have the following problem:
I have to move a web content within a web content Management System from one folder to another. Therefore I have to click on a "Select" button to specify a target folder, then an iframe opens up where I can navigate through the "tree structure" of the folders.
The original page looks like this:
original page with "Select"-button

[image]
The structure of the web content management system is as follows:
Home

```
-Test(=Parent Folder):  
        -UniqueTitle  
        -UniqueTitle2
```

Because the folder that I want to adress(UniqueTitle2) lies one hierarchy below my current folder(I am in UniqueTitle), I have to click on the parent Folder "TEST" to go one hierarchy back. This is a link to the "TEST"-folder.

iframe where you can select the target folder

[image]

The problem is that on the original page below the iframe, the same Link to the "TEST"-folder exists as a breadcrumb. So if selenium clicks on the href link, it actually clicks the link on the original page, and not the one in the iframe.

I tried the following:
to select the iframe:

```
storeAttribute|css=iframe.dialog-iframe-node@id|iframeIDE
selectFrame|id=${iframeID}
```

to click on the link:

```
clickAndWait|link=TEST

clickAndWait|//a[contains(@href,'https://www.companyname.com/language/projectname/manage/maintenance/web-content-management[...]folderid=465576')]
```

Here is a HTML Snippet of the iframe:

```
<a href="https://www.companyname.com/language/projectname/manage/maintenance/web-content-management?p_p_id=15&amp;p_p_lifecycle=0&amp;p_p_state=pop_up&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;_15_struts_action=%2Fjournal%2Fselect_folder&amp;_15_folderId=4655761" data-direction-right="true" data-folder-id="4655761">TEST</a>
```

How can I differentiate between these two, so my script will click within the iframe?

Thank you in advance and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The HTML you provided is of an `<a>` tag. Can you show us the `<iframe>` tag as well?

Comment: hi, here is the iframe tag: `<iframe class="dialog-iframe-node " id="_15_selectFolder_iframe_" name="_15_selectFolder_iframe_" src="https://www.companyname.com/language/projectname/manage/maintenance/web-content-management?p_p_id=15&amp;p_p_lifecycle=0&amp;p_p_state=pop_up&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;_15_struts_action=%2Fjournal%2Fselect_folder&amp;_15_folderId=7190132" style="height: 523px; width: 680px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

you have two options:

#### 1. don't use iframe, use div or section instead

using this approach, you have to move the code for file selection to the main page. use AJAX to populate the file list to the div. this approach is often called single page application, though you don't need to move everything to a single page, just the file selection codes.

#### 2. set allow-origin header of your iframe to your domain name or *

you should read about how to set this HTTP header.
here are some refs

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 0):

Probably duplicate of [How to switch between frames in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10887059/6698607)

First thing when you want to do something inside iframe is switch to it.

```
WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("iframe")));
```

After that you can click on element.
When you want to back you can use:

```
WebDriver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```