# How to switch from child iframe to main iframe and again from main iframe to normal frames?

Tags: selenium

I  have a nested iframe. I am in child frame currently,Now i want to switch to main iframe and then from mainframe i want to switch to normal frames.How to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by normal frames?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch between frames in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the child `frame`, switch to default content like this:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Now you are on the main HTML and you can switch to every frame again. If you want to switch on nested frames, you have to do it step by step.

More information you can get in this [tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html#3).

Answer (score 1):

Scenario : Nested iframe.

**iframeMain

iframeParent

iframechild**

Assume you are in **ifrmaechild** :

When you do `driver.switchTo().parentFrame();` : you will go to iframeParent .
But when you do `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` : you will go to main HTML of page.
Note that in this case you will not go to iframeMain.

So, in your case you should do : `driver.switchTo().parentFrame();` to go to iframe parent. and from here you should use : `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` to go to default DOM tree.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes understood.Thank you

Comment: @vigneshvicks  :If this answer was helpful , please accept it by clicking on check mark which is just besides my answer and under the down vote button. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

As per your scenario, Currently you are in `childFrame`, Now you want to go back to `mainFrame` from `childFrame` like `childFram > mainFrame > childFrame`.

Basically, we can switch over the elements in frames using 3 ways

- By Index
- By Name or Id
- By Web Element

You can switch frame by index or cssSelector. I have also having same problem like you. I implemented resolution for my problem like below.

```
//Below will gives you number of frames available in current page.
Int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
//Switch to frame by it's index
driver.switchTo().frame(4);
//To write text in iframe using below code.
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
body.click();
body.sendKeys("Some text");
//below code will switch to default DOM
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Hope, This will work for you.