# Xpath seems to work in the browser but selenium is unable to pick it

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

On this page "https://www.javatpoint.com/oprweb/test.jsp?filename=htmltable5" the attempt is to pick the first name and the last name if the marks are above 75. Wrote this xpath to find elements which has marks over 75 ".//tbody/tr/td[number(.)>75]" which works in browser but is not found by selenium at runtime. The size of the findElements simply returns 0 and the test fails on putting a wait on condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your `xpath` looks correct but web table your trying to interact is in `frame`. You first need to switch into that particular frame before interacting with `WebElement` inside it.

We can switch into frames using 3 ways.

- By Index
- By Name or Id
- By Web Element

If you search for `iframe` in html, you will find out frame as `id="iframewrapper"` and use below code to switch into frame:

`driver.switchTo().frame("iframewrapper")`

For further details on frames in selenium, kindly refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java) SO thread.