# unable to interact with lightbox in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

step to reach that page. url:http://automationpractice.com/

1. search product.
2. hover a product and click Quick view
3. Click Add to cart
4. Try to interact to any element from light box. // there is no iframe.

[Lightbox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7cOu.png)

[html code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9ZAD.png)

Comment: as I see it is another iframe, try to switch between frames, here is how you can do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java

Comment: @cheparsky,
I don't see any iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Using Selenide this, a little ugly, code working for me:

```java
    @Test
    public void addItemToCart() {
        open("http://automationpractice.com/");
        $(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"homefeatured\"]/li[1]/div/div[1]/div")).hover();
        $(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"homefeatured\"]/li[1]/div/div[1]/div/a[2]/span")).click();
        switchTo().frame($x("//*[@id=\"index\"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/iframe"));
        $x("//*[@id=\"add_to_cart\"]/button").shouldBe(visible, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        $x("//*[@id=\"add_to_cart\"]/button").click();
        $x("//*[@id=\"layer_cart_product_price\"]").shouldBe(visible, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        assert $x("//*[@id=\"layer_cart_product_price\"]").text().equals("$16.51");
        $x("//*[@id=\"layer_cart\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/a/span").click();
        assert $("#cart_title").text().equals("Shopping-cart summary");
    }
```

As I said a problem was in iframe.