# Selenium with powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium, iframe

I am trying to use Selenium with PowerShell. I have to capture a search button, but i am not able to do so.
The element needs to be captured is

```
<a id="btnAdvSearchMenu" class="searchbox-btn" href="/AdvancedSearch.aspx" style="display: none;"></a>
```

I have the html as:
[image]

When i hover the search option, it takes me to "btnAdvSearchMenu" tag.

I am using below PowerShell code to capture this. Please suggest if i am missing something.

```
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByClassName("searchbox-btn").click()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to click invisible element. In the element XML you shared you can see `style="display: none;"`.
Selenium imitates real user GUI actions. As a user you normally can't click invisible elements.
Also, there may be more problems with you code that we can't see since you shared only this information.
**UPD**
The updated XML shows that the element you trying to access is inside the iframe. In order to access elements inside iframe you need to switch driver to that iframe. Also, when finished and you will want to access elements out of that iframe block you will need to switch to the default content.
I know how to do that with normal languages like Python and Java but not a Powershell, I'm sorry. But I'm sure you can find examples for that here in Stackoverflow.

Comment: updated the ques with more info

Comment: @kawade see the updated answer

Comment: Please let me know how to do that using python/Java, i will get an idea and will try to implement in PowerShell

Comment: You can simply google that with something like "selenium switch to iframe" it will give you a lot of examples like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java and much more

Comment: Thanks Buddy. i tried something like $ChromeDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(2); $ChromeDriver.FindElementByClassName("searchbox").SendKeys("test"); but getting error as Exception calling "FindElementByClassName" with "1" argument(s): "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".searchbox"}
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.81)"

Comment: I think here `$ChromeDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(2);` it should be a locator passed to `Frame()` method, not an integer 2

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I rectified the issue, I was calling the wrong iframe.